# How can I verify if a near address is valid in smart contract?

Tags: nearprotocol

Alice.near provided Bob.near as input to a smart contract for some operation. How can the smart contract verify that bob.near is a valid near address that exists before performing requested the operation, without sending any token?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

There's no way for a contract to check the existence of another account if not itself, `sender` or `predecessor`

A contract could ask an oracle to look "from the outside" and verify that an account exists with a contract deployed, but even then there is no guarantee that this verified account won't be deleted before it's called

Comment: What happens to NEAR tokens transferred to addresses that don't exist?  Are they just burned?  The transaction seems to succeed, at least in the simulator ...